# Android Bamboo Build failed- Mapbox download problem

Tags: android, devops, mapbox, bamboo

I am running bamboo pipeline for android app. I am using Mapbox for maps. The build is success in local. The mapbox has changed the integration with username and password authentication and I have configured as per the documentation. In my bamboo build its not working with the following error.

- What went wrong:
  build   25-May-2022 08:04:35    Execution failed for task
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:devDebugCompileClasspath'.
  build   25-May-2022 08:04:35       [33m> [39mCould not resolve com.mapbox.maps:base:10.3.0.
  build   25-May-2022 08:04:35         Required by:
  build   25-May-2022 08:04:35             project :app > com.mapbox.maps:android:10.3.0
  build   25-May-2022 08:04:35          [33m> [39mCould not resolve com.mapbox.maps:base:10.3.0.
  build   25-May-2022 08:04:35             [33m> [39mCould not get resource 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven/com/mapbox/maps/base/10.3.0/base-10.3.0.pom'.
  build   25-May-2022 08:04:35                [33m> [39mCould not GET 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven/com/mapbox/maps/base/10.3.0/base-10.3.0.pom'.
  build   25-May-2022 08:04:35                   [33m> [39mNo PSK available. Unable to resume.
  build   25-May-2022 08:04:35       [33m> [39mCould not resolve com.mapbox.extension:maps-style:10.3.0.
  build   25-May-2022 08:04:35         Required by:
  build   25-May-2022 08:04:35             project :app > com.mapbox.maps:android:10.3.0
  build   25-May-2022 08:04:35             project :app > com.mapbox.plugin:maps-annotation:10.3.0
  build   25-May-2022 08:04:35          [33m> [39mCould not resolve com.mapbox.extension:maps-style:10.3.0.
  build   25-May-2022 08:04:35             [33m> [39mCould not get resource 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven/com/mapbox/extension/maps-style/10.3.0/maps-style-10.3.0.pom'.
  build   25-May-2022 08:04:35                [33m> [39mCould not GET 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven/com/mapbox/extension/maps-style/10.3.0/maps-style-10.3.0.pom'.
  build   25-May-2022 08:04:35                   [33m> [39mpeer not authenticated

Answer (score 0):

This guide for Maps SDK installation using Maven specifies that authentication is required https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/#add-the-dependency. This could be helpful as a pointer on what you'd need to do within a bamboo build.

Comment: I have followed same document, it works fine in android studio and locally. When I try to package and build from bamboo (CI tool) its failing